# Is WHERE [FOO] IN (SELECT [BAR] FROM [...]) guaranteed to give the same execution plan as the equivalent WHERE EXISTS?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, execution-plan, sql-server-2022, exists

In the past, there was a lot of paranoia around `IN`. In particular, I remember claims that it can be optimised differently to an equivalent `WHERE EXISTS`. Is this claim still true? Or is it now guaranteed that `IN` and `WHERE EXISTS` will always give the same execution plans in cases where the two queries are logically equivalent?

I am talking about queries of the following form

```sql
SELECT [...] FROM [FOO] WHERE [FOO_ID] IN (SELECT [FOO_ID] FROM [BAR])
-- Is logically equivalent to...
SELECT [...] FROM [FOO] WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [BAR] WHERE [BAR].[FOO_ID] = [FOO].[FOO_ID])
```

Not that I am not talking about `NOT IN`, `NOT EXISTS`, or using multiple `IN` clauses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim is still true, but it was only ever a concern for long hard-coded `IN` expression lists. The issue is primarily around the extra compilation time, although weird query plans can also result, due to them being compiled into lots of `OR` clauses.

**Your example is different:** it uses an `IN` subquery, which is transformed at an early stage into a semi-join, which is similar to an `EXISTS` anyway. The compilation time should be pretty much the same, and you can see for yourself from [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/N9liUQgw) that the query plans are identical, whether or not the tables are indexed.

Yes, plans are not *always* identical, but that is usually the result of the fact you are getting a fresh compilation, where the optimizer cannot decide between two bad plans (you could equally get this by recompiling the same query). If a good access method is available on the subquery then expect the plans to usually be identical.